# How to use $.get to populate a list using a Rails query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, xml, json

I have some javascript that displays a list of members(links in this case) for that group.
How can I get rails to populate that list?

I can currently get a list of the `members` in group 45 in a browser with a html view using `/groups/45`

I am trying a `$.get` call as shown but I am not sure how to get results into a list.  Presumably via xml or json but not sure how.

My view has:

```
  %ul#sortable
    - @members.each do |loop|
      = content_tag_for :li, loop do
        - construct_hyperlink(loop.url_address, loop.alt_text)
        = sanitize @address_url
        \- #{h @new_link_alt_text}            &nbsp;&nbsp;#{link_to 'details', link_path(loop), {"title" => loop.alt_text}}            &nbsp;&nbsp;#{link_to 'edit', edit_link_path(loop), {"title" => loop.alt_text}}
```

and my js has:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-show-group-members]='true'").bind('click', function() {
    var gid= $(this).data("id");
    var gname= $(this).data("name");
    var links=$.get('/groups/' + gid);
    $('<tr><td colspan="4">Members:</br><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>Delete the <b>'+gname+'</b> group and all its members: <b><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href=\'/groups/'+gid+'\'>Yes</a></b> <b><a href="groups" data-close-group="true">No</b></br></br>').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
    $(this).html("");
  }); 
});
```

but I am not sure how to populate that UL (currently it has placeholder `li`'s

My groups controller has:

```
  def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @members = Link.find_all_by_group_id(params[:id], :order => 'position')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @group }
    end
  end
```

so I could use the `format.xml` or I could add a `format.json` but how do I call that and output a UL that has the group names.

Group is:

```
id: integer, group_name: string, 
created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, group_description: string
```

After I display the members and a link to delete the group, that part works ok.
This is just about listing the members (links) of that group.

I prefer answers that avoid frameworks (other than rails and jquery) for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery $.get() is an asynchronous function, so you are going to need to use a callback here (it's a convenience method that substitutes for $.ajax() without needing to specify that it is a GET request).

Try something in this format

```
$.get(<url, make sure to include the .xml extension>, function(<xml data>) {
    // do something with your xml data
});
```

This is because the server will take time to respond to the request (maybe only a few ms) but you can't directly assign this value to a variable like you would in a language like ruby.

Hope that helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The approach I used in the end that worked was ajax and json:

```
/app/assets/javascript/show_group_members.js.erb

$(function(){
  $("a[data-show-group-members]='true'").bind('click', function() {
    var gid= $(this).data("id");
    var gname= $(this).data("name");
    $('<tr><td colspan="4">Members:</br><ul id="group-members"></ul>Delete the <b>'+
    gname+
    '</b> group and all its members: <b><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" '+
    'data-confirm="Are you sure?" href=\'/groups/'+gid+'\'>Yes</a>'+
    '</b> <b><a href="groups" data-close-group="true">No</b></br></br>')
    .insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
    var the_links=
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/groups/"+gid,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
          DisplayListItems(result);
        },
        "error": function (result) {
          var response = result.responseText;
          alert('Error loading: ' + response);
        } 
      }); 
    function DisplayListItems(list) {
      $.each(list, function(index, element) {
        var itemHTML = ["<li>", element.url_address, ' ', element.group_description, "</li>"].join('\n');
        $("ul#group-members").append(itemHTML);
      });
    } 

    $(this).html("");
  });
});
```

I didn't need to change routes (existing restful resource worked ok) or model.

Group controller just had json added:

```
format.json { render json: @members }
```

The initial link that triggers this (and passes in group id - critical) is:

```
%td= link_to 'Delete group with members', group, :remote => true,
:data => {:show_group_members => true, :id => group.id,:name => group.group_name}
```

(Above line is HAML)